# This program works for small data input but gives a runtime error when large string is eneterd..?? why..?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char* str;
int i;
printf("Enter the String:\n");
gets(str);
int len=strlen(str)-1;
while(len>0&& isspace(str[len]))
len--;
str[len+1]='\0';
printf("Output string:\n%s\n",str);
return 0;
}
```

this code works absolutely fine when input is small like"   trail space" but crashes on large inputs like"            trailing space deleted". I dnt know whay this is happening so please help me. this program removes trailing spaces at the end of string.

Comment: [You should not be using `gets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used).

Comment: when u write like this `char* str;` you have a pointer that points somewhere so when you use that in `gets()` the characters are written somewhere in memory where `str` happens to be pointing.

Answer (score 1):

because `str` is never initialized and is pointing to junk data.

You're lucky and this is Undefined behavior

Instead use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate memory for `str` and it'll do I guess.

Like this: `char *str = malloc(100); // say for 100 characters`

`len` will then be less than or equal to 100 (and should include '\0')

Also note, using `gets()` is a bad idea. instead use `fgets()` or `gets_s()` function

Comment: this dosent work. this malloc assignent gives a void* to char* error. try it on your compiler. I have tried it on both netbeans and devcpp .